# How to get what's between @ and .com in email?

Tags: php

If I have an email myemail@gmail.com, how to store in variable $name only what's between @ and .com? For myemail@gmail.com in variable $name would be 'gmail', and for myemail@yahoo.com, in variable $name would be 'yahoo'.
EDIT: Maybe it would be better to select everything between @ and .I searched for answer before I posted a question here, but I couldn't find an answer.

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: My email address doesn't have `.com` anywhere in it …

Comment: Firstly, have you tried anything for yourself? Secondly, why are you assuming `.com`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a regular expression, or you could use a simpler method to understand.

```
$email = 'somebody@gmail.com';
$parts = explode( '@', $email );
// simple method
$domainArr = explode( '.', $parts[1] );
echo $domainArr[ (count($domainArr)-2) ];  // this line was edited
```

Try that out.

Comment: This will not work with emails with subdomains.

Comment: You're right, I thought of it backwards I'll change it to reflect a simple situation the proper way.

Answer (score 1):

This will get everything between the @ and the first .whatever:

```
preg_match('/@(.+)\.[a-z]+$/', 'nicholas@gmail.mail.com', $matches);
$name = $matches[1]; // gmail.mail
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to remove just `.com` in domain?

If so, you can `str_replace(".com", "", $domain)` and `split("@", $domain)`.

Elsewhere, you need to read [Regular Expressions](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_regular_expression.htm)